# ERROR: Error installing mysql2: ERROR: Failed to build gem native extension on AWS Linux

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, linux, amazon-web-services

I am having some problems when trying to install mysql2 gem for Rails. When I try to install it by running bundle install or gem install mysql2 it gives me the following error:

> Error installing mysql2: ERROR: Failed to build gem native extension.

Also tried the command `yum install mysql-devel` as well. Still getting same error.

How can I fix this and successfully install mysql2?

Answer (score 2):

Please try with running

```
brew install mysql
```

or try with below if you are getting permission denied problems.

```
sudo yum install mysql-devel
```

Comment: which platform your'e using Mac or Ubuntu and it's rails Version ?

Comment: Amazon Linux, rails version: 2.5.8

Comment: I think you shared the ruby version instead of rails. ok try below command
`$ sudo apt-get install libmysqlclient-dev`

Comment: Also may be mysql2 client is missing. You may need to `apt-get install libmysqlclient-dev` or `yum install mysql-devel&apos` and try again.